# about synchronization with using multiple semaphores

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, semaphore

hi there i'm working on an assignment about using POSIX threads with multi semaphores. the brief explanation of assignment is: there are 4 various data packets (char/video/audio/image), each of them carried by a different thread and also we have a shared buffer. maximum threads can work on system will be maintained by the user as an input. for example; if user enters 10 then maximum 10 thread could be created to transmit data packets over a buffer in a given time. now the confusing part for me is, this buffer can contains limited packets instantly. (for example it can contain maximum 10 char packets and 20 video packets etc.) so we have to have different semaphores for each data type. the issue i know how to control the buffer size with semaphore which is very simple, but cant set the correct idea of using semaphores of packets'. even i tried some different methods i always faced with deadlock errors. here is my pseudocode to understand more clearly of my program.

```
define struct packege
define semaphore list

main

initialize variables and semaphores

while threadCounter is less than MaxThreadNumber

switch(random)
case 0: create a character package
    create a thread to insert the package in buffer
case 1: create a video package
    create a thread to insert the package in buffer
case 2: create an image package
    create a thread to insert the package in buffer
case 3: create an audio package
    create a thread to insert the package in buffer

increment  threadCounter by one
end of while

create only one thread which will make the dequeue operation
end of main

producer function

for i->0 to size_of_package
    sem_wait(empty_buffer) // decrement empty_buffer semaphore by size of package

    lock_mutex
        insert item into queueu
        decrement counter of the buffer by size of package
    unlock_mutex

for i->0 to size_of_package
    sem_post(full_buffer) // increment full_buffer semaphore by size of package

end of producer function

consumer function

while TRUE // Loops forever

    lock_mutex

        if queue is not empty
            dequeue

        increment counter of the buffer size of package

    unlock_mutex

for i->0 to size_of_package // The reason why i making the sem_wait operation here is i cant make the dequeue in outer region of mutex.
    sem_wait(full_buffer)
for i->0 to size_of_package
    sem_post(empty_buffer)
end of consumer function
```

with this implementation programe works correctly. but i couldnt use semaphores properly which belongs to threads of packages. i can listen every recommandation and will be appreciated for every answer.

Comment: In your code, the consumer actually doesn't know what sort of data it is reading from the buffer. Is this Ok?

Comment: I *think* you mean to indicate you want to use one semaphore to ration the overall concurrent thread count, and N-semaphores more, one for each packet *type* to ration the number of concurrent threads for any single packet type. Is that even close to accurate? Little confused..

Comment: @didierc yeap there is no problem i arranged the parameters so it works correctly. first of all, i send the structure as a parameter to producer and consumer makes the dequeue operation in mutex. And Queue is defined globally.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how semaphores are used. The buffer's control variables/structures should count how many messages are contained in the buffer and of what types.  The mutex protects the buffer and its control variables/structures against concurrent access by different threads. A semaphore, if used, just signals the state of the buffer to the consumer and has no connection to the sizes of the packets; it certainly doesn't get incremented by the size of the packet!

You would be better advised to use pthread condition variables instead of semaphores. These are used in connection with the pthread mutex to guarantee race-free signalling between threads. The producer loop does this:

- locks the mutex,
- modifies the buffer etc to add new packet(s),
- signals the condition variable, and
- unlocks the mutex.

The consumer loop does this:

- locks the mutex,
- processes all buffered data,
- waits for the condition variable.

Read up on `pthread_cond_init`, `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_cond_wait`.

Comment: actually i know how to use condition variables however in the assignment they wanted just using semaphores from us. like this `For the sake of example, the  buffer can contain 15 multimedia video packets at maximum, meaning that the sixteenth MM-Video packet has to be blocked by a semaphore utilization.`

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an assignment, you probably don't need to have real packets data read and write, but just simulate their handling.

In that case, the problem boils down to how to effectively block the producer threads when they reach the limit of packet they can write in the buffer. At the moment, you are using the semaphore to count the individual elements of a packet written in the buffer, as far as I understand.

Imagine that your writes in the buffer are atomic, and that you just want to count the packets, not the packet elements. Each time a producer writes a packet, it must signal it to the consumer, with the appropriate semaphore, and each time the consumer reads a packet, it must signal it to the appropriate producer.

Let me highlight a few other points:

- The important property of a semaphore is that it will block when it reaches zero. For instance, if its initial value is 10, after 10 successive sem_get, the 11th will block.
- You have 4 types of packets, each with a different threshold on the number that can be written in the buffer.

As I said, the producer must signal that it wrote a packet, but it must also be stopped once it reaches the threshold. To achieve that, you make it acquire the semaphore each time it posts a new packet, with `sem_get`. And you have the consumer do a `sem_post` each time it read a packet, the reverse of what you did with your single semaphore version. However, since you want the producer stop at the threshold, you initialize the semaphore with a capacity of `N - 1`, N being the threshold. Note that you have to signal that a new packet is available after you wrote it in the buffer, otherwise the consumer might block the buffer.

```
producer<type> function

  write_packet()  // put the packet in the buffer
  sem_wait(type)    // signal a new packet is available 
  // (if there's not enough space for another packet, the producer will block here) 

end producer<type> function

consumer function

  while TRUE // Loops forever

      switch packet_available() // look if there's a new packet available
       case video:
         read_packet<video>()
         sem_post(video)
       (...)
       default: // no packet available, just wait a little
          sleep()
      end if
  end while
```

You still need to define the `packet_read`, `packet_write`, and `packet_available` functions, probably using a mutex to limit access to the buffer.

Comment: yeah your understanding is true. the confusing part is. for example assume that i created an image data. than should i use `sem_wait(&empty_image)` and `sem_post(&full_image)` in `case 2: section` or in `producer function`_? On the other hand, is it a correct way that we have 4 diff. types so in consumer semaphore operations will depend on `if-else` statements. for example, `if(datatype==1) sem_wait(&full_video) else if(datatype==2) sem_wait(&empty_image)` etc

Comment: @quartaela : what are empty_image and full_image? Why using 2 different semaphores for image packets?

Comment: empty_image initialized maximum number of image data that buffer can hold and full_image is initialized to 0 which counts full part of buffer. so `For the sake of example, the buffer can contain 15 multimedia video packets at maximum, meaning that the sixteenth MM-Video packet has to be blocked by a semaphore utilization.` so whenever a video packet is transmitted i will signal the producer to add last one. so i define 4 empty an 4 full semaphore variables for each data type. isnt it the rigth way _?

Comment: Is this a requirement of your assigment? If not, just use 4 semaphores, one per packet type, and things will get easier.

Comment: yeap that is the requirement of assignment. well this is the confusing part as i said. :). however, i may not do this part its just getting more complex

Comment: It seems a bit odd. There's no need for 2 semaphores per packet type. Each producer should use one semaphore to indicate that it wrote a packet. And the consumer should check every semaphore, and indicate when it has read a packet from a given type.

Comment: actually we dont have to use 2 semaphores per packet type. that was my assumption. it just indicates we have to use semaphores per packet. so for my understanding i thought i have to use 2 semaphores per packet type. Otherwise, how can i handle with the limitation on packets in the buffer.